# will Apple review team allow to live a native app on AppStore

Tags: objective-c

our application is accessible only after registration  through social media or signup process on the app itself.(there is no any guest user/skip button by which user can open the App). our question is are we violating the the Apple human interface guidelines? our application will be rejected during review before live on the App store?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide apple review team a registered account when submit for review, put it in App Review Information section in app store connect.

Comment: thank you kellying !!! is it necessary to have an skip or guest user button, so that user can see the app without getting registered.? as if we are not placing any such type of button, user is insist to get registered with the app

Comment: It isn't a must to provide a skip or guest button, review team will login with the account you provided.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your app and not violating any of Apple human interface guidelines, at time of submission of app on `iTunes Store` provide testing user credentials, so review team can log-in to app and can check.

When you `Prepare for Submission` there is option available for `Sign-in required`, check on this and fill user name and password.

[image]

Comment: @iPiyush accept the answer if works for you, it helps others too in choosing correct answer.